# is it possible to have a recursive vector in C++?

Tags: c++, parsing, recursion, vector

I am writing a kind of recursive descent parser. In the first stage of my syntax tree, I hold the model pieces I am parsing in a vector. The first piece is the left hand side piece (lhs) and the remaining pieces are right hand side pieces (rhs). Lhs plus the rhs pieces constitutes a production rule (pr). Any of the rhs pieces may themselves be a pr where its first piece is an lhs piece. That pr's lhs piece is also the piece it occupies in the pr whose type I call 'sub'. For example, let pr1 = lhs10 rhs11 sub12 rhs13 and pr2 = lhs20 rhs21 rhs22. lhs20 and sub12 would be the same piece. I am getting an 'inside vector' error probably because I am doing a push_back on the same kind of object as the surrounding object, but is there a way to achieve this kind of recursivity using smart-pointered objects in containers like vector?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct AbstractSyntaxTree;
typedef std::shared_ptr< AbstractSyntaxTree > ModelPiece;
typedef std::vector< ModelPiece > ModelPiecesVect;

struct AbstractSyntaxTree
{
  enum LexState
  {
    LHS = 0x0, RHS = 0x1, SUB = 0x2
  };

  ModelPiecesVect modelPiecesVect;
  LexState lexState;
};

int main()
{
  ModelPiece mp;
  ModelPiece lhs10, rhs11, sub12, rhs13;
  ModelPiece lhs20, rhs21, rhs22;

  lhs10 = std::make_shared< AbstractSyntaxTree >();

  mp->modelPiecesVect.push_back( lhs10 ); // fails here with '... _Ptr points inside vector' (see code fragment below)
  mp->modelPiecesVect.push_back( rhs11 );
  mp->modelPiecesVect.push_back( sub12 );
  mp->modelPiecesVect.push_back( rhs13 );
  mp->modelPiecesVect[ 2 ]->modelPiecesVect.push_back( lhs20 );
  mp->modelPiecesVect[ 2 ]->modelPiecesVect.push_back( rhs21 );
  mp->modelPiecesVect[ 2 ]->modelPiecesVect.push_back( rhs22 );

/*
  bool _Inside( const value_type *_Ptr ) const
  { // test if _Ptr points inside vector
    return ( _Ptr < this->_Mylast && this->_Myfirst <= _Ptr );  // 'this' is null
  }
*/

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

```
typedef std::shared_ptr< AbstractSyntaxTree > ModelPiece;
```

This:

```
ModelPiece mp;
```

is a null pointer. You have to assign something to it, or `mp->modelPiecesVect` causes undefined behavior. Similarly, these:

```
ModelPiece lhs10, rhs11, sub12, rhs13;
ModelPiece lhs20, rhs21, rhs22;
```

have to be initialized (`sub12` in particular), or later `mp->modelPiecesVect[ 2 ]->modelPiecesVect` will fail in the same manner.

Apart from this, what you're doing should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
mp->modelPiecesVect.push_back( lhs10 );
```

`mp` is not initialized here